# Reborrowing of mutable reference

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, mutable-reference

When I wondered how a mutable reference could move into a method, all the questions began.

```
let a = &mut x;
a.somemethod(); // value of a should have moved
a.anothermethod(); // but it works.
```

I've googled a lot. (really a lot)
And I've noticed that a mutable reference passed as a parameter to a function, always undergoes the following transformation. (which is called reborrowing)

```
fn test(&mut a) -> ();

let a = &mut x;
test(a); // what we write in code.
test(&mut *a); // the actual action in code.
```

So, I have googled more about "reborrowing", for its detail.

And this is what I've got.

In any of codes, x refers to an arbitrary data. I don't mention it because I don't think the type of it is important for discussion. (However, I used i32 in my own).

```
let a = &mut x;
let b = &mut *a; // a isn't available from now on
*a = blahblah; // error! no more access allowed for a
*b = blahblah; // I've wrote this code not to confuse you of the lifetime of b. If not mentioned, it always live till the scope ends.
```

```
let a = &mut x;
{
    let b = &*a;
    // *a = blahblah in this scope will throw an error, just like above case.
}
*a = blahblah; // but this works.
```

So alright. It's quite interesting. It seems like `b` borrows not only `x` but also `a`.

Perhaps, we can clarify reborrowing like this : `&'a *(&'b mut x)`.
It has borrowed `x` (which has a lifetime 'a in here),
but also borrowed `a` (which has a lifetime 'b).

So I ran the following code to confirm my conjecture.

```
let x: i32 = 1; // I wanted to make it clear that x lives in this scope.
let b;
{
    let a = &mut x;
    b = &mut *a;
}
*b = 0;
```

But this works!

What??
But I just decided to get this.
`&'a mut *&mutx`, not `&'a mut *&'b mutx`.

I had no idea why `mut x` is unavailable during the lifetime of `&mut *&mutx` nor why `mut x` is re-available after the lifetime of `&mut *&mutx`, but "okay, let's just say so".

But look at this. It's totally out of my mind for a clear and general understanding.

```
let x: i32 = 1;
let b;
{
    let a = &mut x;
    let b = &**&a;
} // error!! a should live longer than b!
```

Wasn't lifetime simply relying on what the real data `b` is referring to???
`&'a **& &mut x`, not `&'a **&'b &'c mut x`.

And now what??

`&'a **&'b &mut x` ??? (which was my guess).

How should I accept this complicated situation?

Comment: My expression of lifetime is totally nonsense. Sorry for my bad question. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are some great questions! I'll do my best to answer the ones I can.

The Rust Reference is a great place for finding answers to questions like this, about the deeper semantics of Rust.

First, for your question about method resolution, [the Reference
says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html):

> When looking up a method call, the receiver may be automatically
> dereferenced or borrowed in order to call a method. This requires a
> more complex lookup process than for other functions, since there may
> be a number of possible methods to call. The following procedure is
> used:
>
> The first step is to build a list of candidate receiver types. Obtain
> these by repeatedly dereferencing the receiver
> expression's type, adding each type encountered to the list, then
> finally attempting an unsized coercion at the end, and adding the
> result type if that is successful. Then, for each candidate `T`, add
> `&T` and `&mut T` to the list immediately after `T`.
>
> For instance, if the receiver has type `Box<[i32;2]>`, then the
> candidate types will be `Box<[i32;2]>`, `&Box<[i32;2]>`, `&mut Box<[i32;2]>`, `[i32; 2]` (by dereferencing), `&[i32; 2]`, `&mut [i32; 2]`, `[i32]` (by unsized coercion), `&[i32]`, and finally `&mut [i32]`.

The link above goes into more detail.

For the rest of your questions, I think this is mostly about type coercion. [Some relevant coercions are](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types):

> - `&mut T` to `&T`
> - `&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`
> - `&mut T` to `&mut U` if `T` implements `DerefMut<Target = U>`

Notably, `&U` and `&mut U` both implement `Deref<Target = U>`, and `&mut U` also implements `DerefMut<Target = U>`. Therefore, the second/third rules lead to the following coercions:

| Let `T` be: | Coerce from | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `&U` | `&&U` | `&U` |
| `&U` | `&mut &U` | `&U` |
| `&mut U` | `&&mut U` | `&U` |
| `&mut U` | `&mut &mut U` | `&mut U` |

---

Now with the reference out of the way, let's look at your questions in more detail:

> ```rust
> let a = &mut x;
> let b = &mut *a; // a isn't available from now on
> *a = blahblah; // error! no more access allowed for a
> *b = blahblah; // I've wrote this code not to confuse you of the lifetime of b. If not mentioned, it always live till the scope ends.
> ```

In order to write into a reference, it clearly must be a mutable (aka unique) reference. When you write `let a = &mut x`, now `a` is the only way to access `x`. Now when you write `let b = &mut *a`, it essentially means `let b = &mut *(&mut x)`, which simplifies to `let b = &mut x`.

Here, `b` mutably borrows `a`, Rust will not let you use `a` until `b` is destroyed... or so it seems for now.

> ```rust
> let a = &mut x;
> {
>     let b = &*a;
>     // *a = blahblah in this scope will throw an error, just like above case.
> }
> *a = blahblah; // but this works.
> ```

Here, `let b = &*a` turns into `let b = &*(&mut x)`, so `let b = &x`. No matter what kind of reference `b` is, `a` is a mutable reference and must be unique, so you can't use it until `b` is gone (out of scope).

> ```rust
> let mut x: i32 = 1; // I wanted to make it clear that x lives in this scope.
> let b;
> {
>     let a = &mut x;
>     b = &mut *a;
> }
> *b = 0;
> ```

(I assume you meant `let mut x`).

Now this is where it gets interesting. Here, since `a` and `b` both mutably point to the same object, Rust will not let you use `a` until `b` is destroyed. It seems like the reasoning should be, "since `b` mutably borrows `a`", but that's actually not the case. Normally, `b` would in fact borrow `a`, and this is the case for smart pointers like `Box`, `std::cell::RefMut`, etc. However, references get special treatment: Rust can analyze the memory they point to.

So when you write `let b = &mut *a`, `b` doesn't actually borrow `a`! It only borrows the data `a` points to. This distinction wasn't relevant before, but here it is what allows the code to compile.

As for your last example, I can't get it to break in the way you described.