# Why into_iter can be called on an iterator reference?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, move-semantics, borrow-checker

I can implement `Iterator` trait for my struct, and get `IntoIterator` implemented for free, thanks to the blanket implementation.

```rust
struct Foo {}

impl Iterator for Foo {
    type Item = ();
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> { None }
}

fn bar(foo: Foo) {
    foo.into_iter(); // implemented automatically for my struct
}
```

But why can I also do this?

```rust
fn bar(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.into_iter(); // works; but shouldn't into_iter require ownership?
}
```

The implementation of the into_iter method seems to require ownership of the value:

```rust
impl<I: Iterator> const IntoIterator for I {
    type Item = I::Item;
    type IntoIter = I;

    #[inline]
    fn into_iter(self) -> I {
        self
    }
}
```

What allows the method into_iter to accept mutable reference when it is defined to take ownership?

Is there a way to make the method `move_out` in the following example to behave like the method `into_iter`?

```rust
trait A {}
trait B {
    fn move_out(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T: A> B for T {
    fn move_out(self) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

struct Foo {}
impl A for Foo {}

fn bar(foo: &mut Foo) {
    foo.move_out(); // compile error
}
```

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer, but I believe the two pieces needed to understand this are the [blanket implementation of `Iterator` for `&mut I`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-for-%26mut%20I) and [reborrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65474162/reborrowing-of-mutable-reference). `foo.into_iter()` is equivalent to `IntoIterator::into_iter(&mut *foo)` which calls the `&mut I` blanket implementation and reborrows the `&mut` ref so it remains usable afterwards.

Comment: If you use clippy, it should warn you about using `into_iter()` “incorrectly”: https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#into_iter_on_ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward any type `T` that implements `Iterator` also implements [`Iterator` for `&mut T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-for-%26mut%20I). And [all types implementing `Iterator` implement `IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-I) which allows you to call `into_iter` on them in the first place.

You can make `A` and `B` behave the same way by simply adding the same blanket implementation `Iterator` has:

```rust
impl<T: A> A for &mut T {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff2e67b5fd4d04ea07bb86541af3cd11)